# Control the finish of activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-button, back

There are two activities in my app

```
Activity A: Select Country
Activity B: Select Region
```

First I enter Activity A, select a country, then will jump to Activity B, and I would like to keep the case like this:

- requirement 1 : if in Activity B press back, then go back Activity A and select country again,
- requirement 2 : if in Activity B select region, then finish the Activity A

The problem is, if I `startActivity()` to open B,  then finish Activity A , it can not meet the requirement 1, but otherwise I can not fit requirement 2.

Is there simpler way besides using `onActivityResult` in Activity A? Can I directly finish A in Activity B?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user select a region call the activity C (the one before activity A) with below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityC.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

read [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

Use have to use **startActivityForResult** for starting the activity

Refer the documentation on it
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html